# Content appears then disappears and then appears again

Tags: jquery, html, css, performance, pagespeed

I needed some help with a website that my team was developing. I issue is basically that the website is very slow due to the following reason.

When a page loads, you can see all the content without the style applied to it. Then the text disappears and after a few seconds appears with the right style applied to it. We though it was a CSS issue...couldn't find one, then we thought it was a jquery issue, couldn't find that either.

Here is a link to an internal page, if you want to review it. http://securetransactions.biz/universal/about-us/

Comment: have you tried to review where the bottlenecks are in Chrome console or firebug? Looking at the network tab in browser I'm am getting a lot of 404 not founds of resources during page loading.

Answer (score 0):

What it seems to be to me is that your server is very slow so the html loads while the css is still loading so it shows up as it would with no css applied, once the css is loaded it "refreshes" to the way it is supposed to look.

It may also be your local internet where ever you're loading it from.

This assumption is coming because it loads fine for me, also I have experienced this happening to me on a word press if I am changing files on the server while i try to load the site.